# Number of possible heaps on $\{1,...,2^h-1\}$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relation, heaps, enumeration, check-my-answer

> Let $C_h$ be the number of possible heaps for the set of keys $\{1,...,2^h-1\}$. Determine a recurrence relation for $C_h$ via the substitution method and prove it.
>
> **Definition**
>
> A binary tree is *ordered* if the key at every node is smaller than the keys at its children.
>
> An ordered binary tree of height $h$ is called a *heap* if the tree induced by all levels except the last is a complete binary tree and all leaves are "as much to the left as possible".

So what I've come up with is this expression:

$$C_h=\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{h} (2^{i-1})!$$

The intuition behind it is that with every  increment by $1$ of $h$ the tree gains $2$ times more leaves than before and the possibilities of ordering these leaves can be determined via the factorial operation. Does that make sense?

Comment: What is a leftist heap? What is the "faculty operation"?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leftist_tree I didn't translate correctly, it should've said factorial operation

Comment: Unfortunately, the Wikipedia article doesn't contain a definition of leftist heap – it just contains some equivocal "hints". I found a definition in some [online slides](http://webdiis.unizar.es/asignaturas/TAP/material/chap4.pdf): a heap is *leftist* if for each node, the *rank* of its left child is at least as large as the rank of its right child, where the rank of a node is the depth of the shallowest leaf in the subtree rooted at the node.

Comment: I can't really follow your argument.

Comment: Yes, what you've found explains it better. I had one explanation in my lecture notes which are in german unfortunately. What formula would you propose if mine seems to be based on a wrong approach ?

Comment: You haven't really explained your approach, unfortunately.

Comment: It is false to say that if $h$ is incremented by $1$, then the tree has twice as much leaves: a leftist tree of size $n$ could be completely linear, with a height of $n$ if all nodes have no right child.

Comment: Even my description is incomplete, since it doesn't explain whether nodes with a single (left) child are allowed.

Comment: So I tried to translate the german description into english. I hope it makes more sense now. I should've done that right away. The case that we have a tree that branches out exclusively to the left seems to be forbidden by this definition.

Comment: Maybe this definiton makes my train of thought more clear ?

Comment: What you have described is usually called a *heap*. A *leftist heap* is something else. Given that, let me suggest that you also define what you mean by "ordered binary heap", and also work out a few small examples, so that we all know what question we're trying to answer.

Comment: In an orderd tree there is a order relation that lets you compare the children of each node and order them by there "size" in this relation. I'm sorry for this confusion, I was expecting that the definitions in my lecture notes where a little bit more common.

Comment: In a (min-)heap the value at each node is smaller than the value of its children. Is this what you mean by "ordered heap"?

Comment: Exactly! Just in our case we have a max heap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $n = 2^h-1$, the heap is just a complete binary tree of height $h$. Clearly $C_0 = C_1 = 1$. For $h > 1$, we can decompose the heap as follows:

- The root must be 1.
- Each of the two children are heaps of size $2^{h-1}-1$ on their respective values.
- The $2^h-2$ values other than the root can be divided arbitrarily to the two children (each gets exactly $2^{h-1}-1$).

This gives us the recurrence
$$
C_h = \binom{2^h-2}{2^{h-1}-1} C_{h-1}^2.
$$
Unrolling this recurrence gives
$$
C_h = \binom{2^h-2}{2^{h-1}-1} \binom{2^{h-1}-2}{2^{h-2}-1}^2 \binom{2^{h-2}-2}{2^{h-3}-1}^4 \cdots \binom{2^1-2}{2^0-1}^{2^{h-1}}.
$$
This is [A056972](https://oeis.org/A056972). You can prove inductively that
$$
C_h = \frac{(2^h-1)!}{\prod_{k=1}^h (2^k-1)^{2^{h-k}}}.
$$
This formula also has a combinatorial interpretation. Start with one of the $(2^h-1)!$ possible permutations of keys. Swap the root with the minimal key (1), and then do the same recursively on both children. This gives a heap. Going in the other direction, we can start with a heap, and then go over all internal nodes in non-increasing order of depth, swapping the root with an arbitrary node in the subtree. There are $2^{h-k}$ nodes at depth $h-k$, and each of them has $2^k-1$ nodes at its subtree. This gives the denominator.

Comment: Upon reading this answer again, I still do not fully understand why we have to square the $C_{h-1}$

Comment: Each heap of height $h$ consists of a root together with *two* heaps of height $h-1$.

Comment: Oh ok! I get it, hence we have to multiply $C_{h-1}$ with itself inorder to get all the combinations possible  just like when you have 2 coins with heads and tails you have $(h1,h2) ; (h1,t2) ; (t1,h2) ; (t1,t2)$ as the 4 possible outcomes of the coin flips

Answer (score 3):

The definition you give looks like the definition of a [complete tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees). With the restriction that nodes are in $[\![1, 2^h-1]\!]$, then it is also a **perfect tree** of height $h$.

Instead of looking at the leaves, you should look at the root of the tree: since the tree is perfect, it has two children of size $2^{h-1}-1$ (this is how $C_{h-1}$ appears). You just have to think of how to split $2^{h}-2$ keys between left and right (the key of the root is uniquely determined, since it is a heap).

I will edit this answer if it is not clear enough.

Comment: Yes indeed, the definition of a complete tree fits the definition in my lecture notes.